# Make "Ship to different address" mandatory if specific products are in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to add a snipped to activate the "Ship to other address" open by default, when a specific product is in the checkout. 
I found [Enable 'Ship to a different address' check box for specific products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747502/enable-ship-to-a-different-address-check-box-for-specific-products-in-woocomme/53747800#53747800) related answer thread which is working perfectly!

However, it should not be possible to unselect the check box "Ship to other address". If a specific product is in the checkout, then providing a different shipping address is required.

Goal: Gray-out the "Ship to other address" checkbox for those specific products.

I just changed [in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747800/3730754) `$products_ids = array(10800, 11907);` to feet my needs.

I already tried to unhook the function but then the whole code does not work. So I'm searching the best way to gray-out that checkbox but keep the code above fully working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood, you want to keep your code functionality, disabling the checkbox.

The best thing is to hide the checkbox first. Then **to avoid the shipping address to be shown or hidden** by clicking on the checkbox label, jQuery will remove it when it is checked.

The php code (and inline CSS):

```
// Hide the checkbox (inline CSS) - Only on checkout page
add_filter( 'wp_head', 'shipping_address_checkbox_ccs' );
function shipping_address_checkbox_ccs() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        ?><style>body.checkout-hide-checkbox #ship-to-different-address-checkbox { display:none; } body.checkout-hide-checkbox #ship-to-different-address label { cursor: default; }</style><?php
    }
}

// Conditional function
function mandatory_shipping_address(){
    $products_ids = array(10800, 11907);
    $found = $others_found = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), $products_ids ) ){
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $others_found = true;
        }
    }
    return $found && ! $others_found ? true : false;
}

// Conditionally Enable checkbox (checked)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_address');
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_address( $checked ) {
    return mandatory_shipping_address() ? true : $checked;
}

// Conditionally Add a body class - Only on checkout page
add_filter( 'body_class', 'shipping_address_checkbox_body_class' );
function shipping_address_checkbox_body_class( $classes ) {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && mandatory_shipping_address() ) {
        $classes[] = 'checkout-hide-checkbox';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

The jQuery code:

```
// Remove the checkbox when is checked - Only on checkout page
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cart_needs_shipping_address_js');
function cart_needs_shipping_address_js() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    wc_enqueue_js( "jQuery( function($){
    var a = '#ship-to-different-address-checkbox';
    if( $(a).is(':checked') ) {
        $(a).remove(); // Remove checkbox
    } 
    });");
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

So when checkbox is checked you will get *(for your defined products)*:

[image]

Comment: I just found out that when I click on the lable text is possible to collapse and decollapse the the shippings fields. For us, we want to have a different text there in H2 instead of H3 so we will hide that lable also and echo a new text there. Then it is fixed.

Comment: @Nik7 You can use the jquery code + all other code… This will avoid  to collapse and decollapse the shippings fields, as the checkbox is first hidden ,and 500ms after, removed by jquery.

Comment: I now use body.checkout-hide-checkbox #ship-to-different-address to hide the lable. Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could **add a custom class to the checkout body tag** when there are products in the cart.

So with a CSS rule you can hide the *"Ship to a different address?"* checkbox.

Using this answer:

- [Enable 'Ship to a different address' check box for specific products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747502/enable-ship-to-a-different-address-check-box-for-specific-products-in-woocomme/53747800#53747800)

You can take the code and create a new custom function *(returns the same result as before, the function has not been modified except the product ids)*:

```
function check_if_product_is_in_cart() {

    $products_ids = array( 10800, 11907 );
    $found = $others_found = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if (in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), $products_ids ) ){
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $others_found = true;
        }
    }

    if ( $found && ! $others_found ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
        
}
```

Then **you can enable** or **disable the checkbox** based on the result of the function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_address');
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_address( $checked ) {
    return check_if_product_is_in_cart();
}
```

Finally you can use the same function **to add the custom class to the checkout body tag**:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class' );
function add_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        return $classes;
    }
    if ( check_if_product_is_in_cart() ) {
        $classes[] = 'hide_ship_to_different_address_checkbox';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

At this point **you just have to add the CSS rules** in the style sheet of your active theme:

- [Make WooCommerce checkout shipping fields visible and remove "Ship to different address?" checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045316/make-woocommerce-checkout-shipping-fields-visible-and-remove-ship-to-different/66052609#66052609)

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: It's working :) But it breaks my whole layout. After add the filter : "add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class' );" the layout is broken

Comment: Now works. The problem occurred on pages other than checkout.