# WooCommerce how to check if Shipping Methods are being displayed at checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I would like to add a message just above the Total on the Checkout Page if the shipping methods area of the cart order review area is being shown or not. This is the table row within the #order_review table that isn't displayed unless I think there is at minimum information set (for USA) Country, State, City and Zip Code.

So if no address has been entered in billing or if 'ship to a different address' is checked, and a shipping address has been entered.

Looking in the review-order.php template file W.C. uses: if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping()){} so I tried using that as a conditional, but it seems to always return true:

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'rnr_needs_shipping');

function rnr_needs_shipping(){

   if( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ){

   echo'<tr>My message</tr>';

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

If in WooCommerce Settings > Shipping > Options > Shipping destination, "Default to customer billing address" is selected, the customer can use the billing address as shipping address: In this case, the shipping checkbox is unchecked by default, shipping fields are not displayed and if the customer place its order, the shipping fields values are cloned from the billing values. That's why the title is *"Ship to a different address?"*…

You can force shipping fields to be displayed in 2 different ways:

- In WooCommerce Settings > Shipping > Options > Shipping destination, select "Default to customer shipping address".
- By adding `add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_true' );`

The only way to check if the shipping checkbox is checked on checkout load is:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'checkout_needs_shipping_address');
function checkout_needs_shipping_address(){
   if( 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ){
       echo'<tr>My message</tr>';
   }
}
```

**Note:** If in WooCommerce Settings > Shipping > Options > Shipping destination, *"Force shipping to the customer billing address"* is selected, the shipping form will not be displayed.

---

Original answer.

The following code will:

- always display the checkout shipping fields,
- hide "Ship to a different address?" checkbox,
- replace "Ship to a different address?" text with "Shipping details".

Normally shipping fields, when displayed, are required, so if the customer hasn't filled all required shipping fields, an error notice will be displayed avoiding place order.

The code:

```php
// Show checkout shipping fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_true' );

// Hide "Ship to a different address?" checkbox (inline CSS)
add_filter( 'wp_head', 'shipping_address_checkbox_ccs' );
function shipping_address_checkbox_ccs() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        ?><style>#ship-to-different-address-checkbox{display:none;} 
        #ship-to-different-address label{cursor: default;}</style><?php
    }
}

// Change "Ship to a different address?" text
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text, $original_text, $domain ) {
    if( is_checkout() && 'Ship to a different address?' === $original_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Shipping details';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Related: [Make "Ship to different address" mandatory if specific products are in WooCommerce cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573320/make-ship-to-different-address-mandatory-if-specific-products-are-in-woocommer/66573941#66573941)

Comment: I'm not clear on how this answers the original question, or my question is unclear.  I believe this conditional may work to check if the customer's shipping info has been entered (and validated)  at checkout:  if( WC()->cart->show_shipping()  ){ }

Comment: I see that my question is unclear, and I hadn't considered  'Ship to a different address'. I have attempted to clarify my question.